# Как правильно употреблять слова, производные от SMS, и подобные?

Tags: иноязычная-лексика

Слово "эсэмэс" (СМС, SMS, смска) прочно вошло в нашу жизнь. Как Вы считаете, верно ли употребление "СМС - сообщение", "ММС - сообщение" или слово "сообщение" здесь лишнее. Когда начала писать, возник и второй вопрос: как правильнее писать эти слова. Уже несколько лет назад даже глагол видела "отсмсь мне" ("отэсэмэсь")  - ни одной гласной в слове!

Comment: См. также: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/23008/%d0%ad%d1%81%d1%8d%d0%bc%d1%8d%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b5-%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be/444634#444634

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю, "СМС-сообщение" вполне нормально. Только там дефис, не тире, и,  соответственно, без пробелов.

Глагол, конечно, "отэсэмэсить", тут уж аббревиатурой и не пахнет, так что гласные пропускать нельзя. Хотя нормативность такого образования, сами понимаете, ниже плинтуса.

Answer (score 2):

Лопатин: *эсэмэска*, -и, р. мн. -сок (СМС-сообщение, прост.)

На интернет-портале "Грамота.ру":

Как все-таки лучше писать: эсэмэска, sms-ка, смска?
Ответ справочной службы русского языка
Правильное написание: *эсэмэска*. Заметим, что само это слово — разговорное.

Comment: В новом журнале для учителей филологов (приложение к журналу "Вестник образования") "Часть речи" в одной из статей слово написано как "смска". Видно, в Лопатинский справочник заглядывают далеко не все филологи. 
Спасибо за ответ. Но смска - разговорное, СМС-сообщение - -просторечное, а как же правильное,нейтральное, без ограничений?

Answer (score 0):

Не согласен с коллегой. Все же "смс-сообщение" - это плеоназм, хотя и не режет слух, как, впрочем", привычными являются и такие фразы, как "в апреле месяце".

Comment: Ну знаете... SMS - short message serviсe - служба коротких сообщений. Разве *сообщение, пререданное по службе коротких сообщений* - плеоназм? А "СМС-сообщение" просто короткая форма такого значения.   
Не говоря уж о том, что перенесение с английского вообще лишает смысла разговоры о плеоназме, в русском это сочетание не распадается на составляющие.

Comment: Почему? Как это ни странно, но СМС = служба мгновенных сообщений. Нет? По крайней мере, такая интерпретация вполне перекликается с англоязычной расшифровкой аббревиатуры.