# "Эсэмэска" — разве это правильно?

Tags: аббревиатуры

Этот вопрос тут обсуждался и, как я помню, пришли в выводу, что лучше всего писать "СМС-сообщение" или "СМСка". Но сейчас читаю, что, оказывается, правильно "эсэмэска". Но, честно говоря, мне это как-то странно — не помню, чтобы хоть кто-то так писал.

Comment: См также: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/7556/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82-sms-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

думаю, это написание (эсэмэска) недолговечно, как и всякое написание, идущее вразрез с общими принципами. И одного Лопатина не хватит чтобы с этим бороться.
Обсуждения на эту тему не помню, *СМС-сообщение*, конечно, правильно, но не отменяет вопрос о написании собственно ***эсемески***. Именно так, думаю, и закрепится. А через какое-то время и произношение будет соответствующим. Если, конечно, само понятие не устареет. Вслед за, например, пейджером - ну кто сейчас помнит об этом эсемесночном "папе"?

Comment: Мой вопрос был.

Comment: И что там порешили?

Comment: К сожалению, не могу ссылку в комментарий вставлять. Зайдите через мою страничку, пожалуйста, там вопросов не так много.

Comment: Ларf, да без проблем.

http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/7556

Answer (score 7):

Правильно действительно "[эсэмэска](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%FD%F1%FD%EC%FD%F1%EA%E0&all=x)", так как именно такое написание зафиксировано в словаре (Лопатина). Насколько народ эту норму воспримет сказать пока нельзя, но по причине отсутствия других вариантов,  придется признать лопатинский.

Answer (score 3):

Да,именно этот вариант верен. Его и рекомендует Грамота.ру и, насколько я помню, он был включен в Тотальный диктант.